# Facebook tutorial help from a website

Tags: java, android, import

Help. Recently I got a facebook connect tutorial from web http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/tag/android-fbconnect-tutorial/.

The tutorial says I have to compile facebook API into a jar file and then import the jar file to the sample.

What about if I just want to use the code in the API? How to incorporate files in one project to another?

In eclipse, is there a way so that one project would "require" file from another project?

Answer (score 1):

You could just insert Facebook API as another package under src folder. I did this way and it works perfectly.

Comment: Download Facebook Api from Github. Then insert folders to your project.

Comment: I have download the folders. How do I insert them into the project? Sorry I am still new to Eclipse

Comment: just drag it to src folder in your project

Answer (score 1):

Create a project for the FB library.

In Android go to the Project-> Properties -> Android, and click on IsLibrary under the Libraries section.

Now in your own project, go to Project ->Properties ->Android and add the FB Library to your project Libraries.